# Mailchimp API - Query to get all draft campaigns

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to query Mailchimp to get all my campaigns in **draft** status. The following won't work to me (returns unexpectedly an empty result set):

```
use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;

$MailChimp = new MailChimp($MAILCHIMP_APIKEY);

$result = $MailChimp->get('campaigns?status=draft');
```

while the following:

```
$result = $MailChimp->get('campaigns');
```

will return a big number of campaigns, all of them are in **sent** status (and I don't need them). In brief, it seems that the **status** query parameter won't work. Anyone has had any luck filtering with it?